# Backup a wordpress instance with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, wordpress, ftp, raspberry-pi, debian

I have a Wordpress site on an external third-party-server. I am currently backing manually using FileZilla and phpMyAdmin.

I have a Raspberry Pi which I want to use to make automatic backups of my Wordpress instance.

Is there an easy way in Raspbian to download all files from a specific FTP directory (and recursive all sub-dirs)? Or should I do that with Python?

My second question is how to export the "mysql" database by shell?

The web server should not start the backup process, so the existing backup plugins will not work.

Comment: `mysqldump -p -u username database > output.sql` - it will ask for password.

Comment: I use [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/index.html) (in Python) to automate tasks - upload/download from server. But it use SSH connection and rsync command.

Comment: [CurlFtpFS](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) can mount FTP as folder on Linux. Python module [fs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fs/0.5.4a) can use FTP like local file system (but I didn't test it).